# solidity re-entrancy attack explanation

Tags: security, ethereum, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

Hey I have a question about re-entrancy, I get the logic but how come the attacker manages to withdraw again before the balance is set to 0, taking into account transaction time and that both functions in A and B are on the next line

[re-entrancy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILNHg.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say we have 2 contracts. target contract which holds some ether belongs to the attacker contract. And now attacker contract wants to withdraw its money

Attacker contract has 2 functions: `fallback` and `withdraw`

```
// this gets triggered when ether is receive
fallback(){
  A.withdraw()
}

attack(){
  A.withdraw()
}
```

Let's say attacker contract calls `attack` function. This will call the `withdraw` inside target contract:

target contract:

```
withdraw(){
  require balance>0
  send ether
  // before balance gets updated attacker's fallback triggers another withdraw
  // send function will give the control to the attacker's contract
  set balance of attacker =0
}
```

Now target contract will send the `ether` to attacker's contract. When it does, inside attacker's contract `fallback` function is triggered. `fallback` gets executed every time ether is received. I explained [fallback functions in detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69178874/solidity-v0-6-0-fallback-functions-what-are-they-needed-for)

Now attacker's contract is received ether and immediately calls `withdraw` inside target contract. So target contract's `withdraw` function is in a loop  till target contract's balance reaches to 0

If a contract uses `call, send or transfer` which may cause
control flow to the attacker contract, because those functions delegate enough gas for the fallback function. Once the control is passed to the attacker's contract, the state of the target contract will incomplete. target contract lost the contrrol.

[Prevent reentrancy attacks](https://medium.com/coinmonks/protect-your-solidity-smart-contracts-from-reentrancy-attacks-9972c3af7c21)