# `msg.sender` preferred over `tx.origin` in Solidity

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I am new to solidity but I have read at many times that `tx.origin` should be avoided & `msg.sender` should  be used .
There is a given demo on this in solidity [page](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/develop/security-considerations.html#tx-origin). It says like :-

> Never use tx.origin for authorization. Let’s say you have a wallet
> contract like this:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;
// THIS CONTRACT CONTAINS A BUG - DO NOT USE
contract TxUserWallet {
    address owner;

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function transferTo(address payable dest, uint amount) public {
        // THE BUG IS RIGHT HERE, you must use msg.sender instead of tx.origin
        require(tx.origin == owner);
        dest.transfer(amount);    // .transfer is a global variable
    }
}
```

> Now someone tricks you into sending Ether to the address of this
> attack wallet:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;
interface TxUserWallet {
    function transferTo(address payable dest, uint amount) external;
}

contract TxAttackWallet {
    address payable owner;

    constructor() {
        owner = payable(msg.sender);
    }

    receive() external payable {
        TxUserWallet(msg.sender).transferTo(owner, msg.sender.balance);   //  **LINE 1**
    }
}
```

Now , I want to know that how line 1 will drain entire funds from `TxUserWallet`. I think  `transfer()` is a global variable which will just transfer the amount to address in `dest`  which is of attack wallet. How `.transfer()` will trigger `receive()` function of  contract `TxAttackWallet`.
Secondly , In line `TxUserWallet(msg.sender).transferTo(owner, msg.sender.balance);` , why are we writing it as `TxUserWallet(msg.sender)` , like why are we adding (msg.sender) after contract name
and also what values is being passed by writing `msg.sender.balance` ?

Answer (score 4):

you should avoid using `tx.origin` to prevent the Reentrancy attack. [solidity re-entrancy attack explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70920485/solidity-re-entrancy-attack-explanation/70921014#70921014)

Basically, the attacker is withdrawing money from the contract recursively till the balance is 0. So there is a chain of function calls. A reentrancy attack involves two smart contracts. A vulnerable contract and an untrusted attacker’s contract. (`fallback` function is called under multiple conditions and this makes writing code for each condition hard. That is why `receive` is added. `receive` is called only contract receives ether so that fallback should be executed only if a function signature is not implemented within a contract.)

[image]

`msg.sender` is the last caller while `tx.origin` is the
original caller of those recursive function chain.

funcA => funcB => funcC

`msg.sender` is the caller of `funcC` whereas `tx.origin` is the caller of `funcA`

Now to prevent the Reentrancy attack we have to make sure that there is no chain of function calls.

```
require(tx.origin == msg.sender)
```

In your question, story is a little different. Imagine the workflow. You are saying

> Now someone tricks you into sending Ether to the address of this
> attack wallet:

You are sending money to `TxAttackWallet`, so you are initiating the function chains. `tx.origin` is you, the owner, `tx.origin == owner`. Once you send money to `TxAttackWallet`, automatically `receive` of `TxAttackWallet` will be called so this code will be executed recursively. You are in a loop

```
  TxUserWallet(msg.sender).transferTo(owner, msg.sender.balance);
```

You keep transferring funds from your contract to `TxUserWallet`.

Who is the `tx.origin`? It is you because you started this chain of functions so this will always pass:

```
 require(tx.origin == owner);
```

If you were using the `msg.sender==owner`, `msg.sender` would be the `TxUserWallet` so require condition would not pass and no funds would be transferred.

Answer (score 0):

> *How `.transfer()` will trigger `receive()` function of contract `TxAttackWallet`*

The `receive()` function is invoked automatically when you're sending ETH to the contract address without specifying the `data` field.

It is not possible to specify the data field with the `.transfer()` function, you'd need to use the low-level `.call()` for that.

Docs:

- `receive()` - https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.16/contracts.html#receive-ether-function
- `.transfer()` and `.call()` - https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.16/types.html#members-of-addresses

---

> *why are we writing it as `TxUserWallet(msg.sender)` , like why are we adding (msg.sender) after contract name and also what values is being passed by writing `msg.sender.balance` ?*

`TxUserWallet(msg.sender)` is a contract type pointer to the `msg.sender` address (in your case the `TxUserWallet` contract address), expecting it to implement all `public` and `external` functions of `TxUserWallet`.

This way, the `TxAttackWallet` contract expects to be able to call the `transferTo()` function on `msg.sender` and expects to receive empty response, as the `transferTo()` function doesn't return any params.

`msg.sender.balance` returns the native balance (ETH on Ethereum, BNB on Binance Smart Chain, ...) of `msg.sender`, in your case that's the `TxUserWallet` contract address.

Docs:

- contract type `TxUserWallet(msg.sender)` - https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.16/types.html#contract-types
- `.balance` - https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.16/units-and-global-variables.html#members-of-address-types

Comment: In line `TxUserWallet(msg.sender).transferTo(owner, msg.sender.balance);`  shouldn't msg.sender point to `TxAttackwallet` & not `TxUserWallet`. I mean msg.sender points to immediate caller . Now when `.receive()` was executed then the control moved to attack wallet which is not executing `receive()` function , so shouldn't `msg.sender` point to attack wallet. ?

Comment: @Brijesh This attack vector expects the victim (end user, `owner` of `TxUserWallet`) to send a small amount to the `TxAttackWallet` through `TxUserWallet` function `transferTo`. Because of the vulnerability, `TxAttackWallet` is then able to pull all the remaining funds from `TxUserWallet`. So in this context `msg.sender` inside `TxAttackWallet` points to `TxUserWallet` as the immediate caller... If the end user sent ETH to `TxAttackWallet` directly, then `msg.sender` would point to the end user.

Comment: But `receive()` function is being executed by `TxAttackWallet`, after it received funds from `TxUserWallet`. So in line `TxUserWallet(msg.sender).transferTo(owner, msg.sender.balance);` , shouldn't msg.sender point to `TxAttackWallet` ?

Comment: @Brijesh The `receive()` function on `TxAttackWallet` is executed by `TxUserWallet` as they sent the funds... A little personalization to give a more clear example. :) It's "I'm sending funds to a contract so I'm going to call their `receive()` function" - not "I received funds, so I'm going to call my `receive()` function"